# How can I perform dynamic reconfiguration in Scala (like Dyre or XMonad)?

Tags: scala, configuration

A fairly common method of configuration for Haskell applications is having the program as a library, with a main function provided with a bunch of optional parameters for configuration. Upon being run, the executable itself looks for a dotfile containing a main function using this default function, which it then compiles and run instead. This sort of configuration scheme allows the user to add arbitrarily complex functionality without recompiling the entire program. Examples of this are the [Dyre library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dyre) and the [XMonad window manager](http://www.nepherte.be/step-by-step-configuration-of-xmonad/). How can this be done in Scala cleanly? It appears that SBT does something similarly internally.

Using SBT externally would require having the sources of the whole program somewhere, and lacks the cleanliness of just having a single dotfile. Typesafe config, Configrity, Bee Config, and fig all seem to only be meant for normal string based configuration.

Comment: Sounds like SBT, kinda.

Comment: I don't understand the close votes. The question is perfectly sensible, clear, and can be answered concretely.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/typesafehub/config is a great config library.

supports files in three formats: Java properties, JSON, and a human-friendly JSON superset

Comment: Also, the motivation for the typesafe config is that you should never ever put your configuration in the code, but externalize it

Comment: Err, isn't this nothing like Dyre or Xmonad?